# How to fill the surface of the JButton completely with an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, label, jbutton, bufferedimage

Ive tried to fill the "surface" of the Jbutton completely with an ImageIcon. My result so far is:

[image]

As you can see there is still some space between the edge of the "Exit"-Label and the edge of the button. You can see the button with the white-blue filling at the background. What I want is to cover this button COMPLETELY with the label.

Is there a way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
    package footballQuestioner;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Beiexamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new MyFrame();

    }

}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        BufferedImage image;
        JLabel label;

    public MyFrame() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        Font font = new Font("Rockwell Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 25);
        JButton button1=new JButton();

        image=getBufferedImage("footballQuestioner/ExitButtonLabel.png");
        image=getScaledImage(250, 100, image);

        label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(750,300);


        button1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
//      button1.setBackground(new Color(0,100,0));
        button1.setFocusPainted(true);
        button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        button1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

        add(button1);

        pack();
        centeringWindow();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public void centeringWindow() {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x;
        int y;

        x = (int) (dimension.getWidth() - getWidth()) / 2;
        y = (int) (dimension.getHeight() - getHeight()) / 2;

        setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public BufferedImage getBufferedImage(String pathName) {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(Beispielfenster.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(pathName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;

    }

    public BufferedImage getScaledImage(int width, int height,
            BufferedImage orginalImage) {

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        // 2. Use the Graphic object to draw a new image to the image in the
        // buffer
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawImage(orginalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);

        g.dispose();

        return image;

        // Image image=orginalImage.getImage();
        // Image newImage=image.getScaledInstance(width,height,
        // Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        // ImageIcon imageIcon=new ImageIcon(newImage);
        //
        // return imageIcon;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the border to `EmptyBorder` so there is no padding within your button.

**add this:**

```
button1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

**my result:**

[image]

Comment: @user3133542 it is working fine on mine.. make sure the height of your image is greater than the button's height.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you ultimately want to achieve you could, set the `contentAreaFilled` property...

[image: Example]

```
button1.setForeground(Color.RED);
button1.setFocusPainted(true);
button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

(note, the frame's content area is yellow to highlight the button)

And/or adjust the `margins` properties...

[image: Example]

```
button1.setForeground(Color.RED);
button1.setFocusPainted(true);
button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button1.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Just as some additional ideas...

Comment: Thank You! The setMargin-Function is exactly what ive searched for!

Comment: There are benefits to using `setBorder`, but you'd probably want to use `setContentAreaFilled` as well